# Interpreter in C++ for Brainfuck printing the wrong results

Tags: c++, console-application, interpreter, brainfuck

I written a Interpreter in C++ for Brainfuck und it works fine with "Hello World" Brainfuck Code to give me the right output. Now I'm trying a different Brainfuck Code, that generates the fibonacci number sequence, but now it just won't work and is just printing some weird symbols and random numbers in the console.

Here is the Code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class BrainFuckInterpreter
{
private:
    std::vector<unsigned char> memory;
    size_t                     pointer;

public:
    BrainFuckInterpreter()
      : memory(30000000, 0)
      , pointer(0)
    {
    }

    void Interpret(const std::string& code)
    {
        size_t              i = 0;
        std::vector<size_t> temp;
        while (i < code.length())
        {
            char input = code[i];
            switch (input)
            {
            case '>':
                ++pointer;
                break;
            case '<':
                --pointer;
                break;
            case '+':
                ++memory[pointer];
                break;
            case '-':
                --memory[pointer];
                break;
            case '[':
                temp.push_back(i);
                break;
            case ']':
                if (memory[pointer] != 0)
                {
                    i = temp.back();
                }
                else
                {
                    temp.pop_back();
                }
                break;
            case '.':
                std::cout << memory[pointer];
                break;
            case ',':
                std::cin >> memory[pointer];
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string          code = R"(+++++++++++
>+>>>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<<<<<<[>[>>>>>>+>
+<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>-]<[>++++++++++[-
<-[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]+<[>[-]<[-]]>[<<[>>>+<<<
-]>>[-]]<<]>>>[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]+<[>[-]<[-]]
>[<<+>>[-]]<<<<<<<]>>>>>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++.[-]]++++++++++<[->-<]>++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.[-]<<
<<<<<<<<<<[>>>+>+<<<<-]>>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]<-[>>.>.<<<
[-]]<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<<[<+>-]>[<+>-]<<<-])";
    BrainFuckInterpreter bfint;
    bfint.Interpret(code);
}
```

Console Output :  ,   8  ,   =  ,   E } ,   R ,   g K ,
Expected Output : 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89

What I tried:

```
        case '.':
            // Output the numerical value without additional characters
            std::cout << static_cast<int>(memory[pointer]) << " ";
            break;
```

There I got this Output: 49 49 44 32 49 49 44 32 50 40 44 32 51 31 44 32 53 13 44 32 56 242 44 32 61 197 44 32 69 125 44 32 82 8 44 32 103 75 44 32 137 25 44 32

Then I tried that:

```
        case '.':
            // Output the numerical value as a character
            putc(memory[pointer], stdout);
            break;
```

Output:  , 8‗, =┼, E } , , gK, ë↓,

Next Try:

```
case '.':
    // Output the numerical value as a character
    putc(static_cast<char>(memory[pointer]), stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    break;
```

Output: , 8‗, =┼, E } , , gK, ë↓,

Next Try:

```
int main()
{
    // Set console code page to UTF-8 (Windows)
    system("chcp 65001");
```

Output: , 8, =, E}, , gK, ,

Comment: Note when using raw strings, the newlines are preserved in the string. It doesn't matter here though, because you skip them in the `default` case.

Comment: It looks like you haven't implemented the `[` instruction correctly by the [looks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#Language_design) of it. If the byte at the data pointer is zero, you still execute the instructions in between, when you actually shouldn't.

Comment: Because that language name offends my delicate sensibilities, could you please censor it to `B****fuck`. Thanks!